# Exploding and Storing Values in an array disregarding Empty Values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have this sample records to parse:

```
@2013-01-19 02:45:00,1.32927,1.33029,1.32909,1.33018,464
@2013-01-19 03:00:00,1.33019,1.33142,1.33019,1.33081,637
@2013-01-19 03:15:00,1.33083,1.33129,1.33069,1.33095,425
@2013-01-19 03:30:00,1.33092,1.3317,1.33045,1.33144,500
@2013-01-19 03:45:00,1.33146,1.33211,1.33095,1.33196,480
@2013-01-19 04:00:00,1.33197,1.33291,1.33166,1.33264,593
@2013-01-19 04:15:00,1.33267,1.33308,1.33234,1.33238,366
@2013-01-19 04:30:00,1.33239,1.33278,1.33236,1.33263,335
```

using this php code, iam trying to store every line in an array with five indices (line was exploded by comma):

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    $data = explode('@', $line);
    foreach($data as $record){
        $val = explode(',',$record);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($val);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

where **$lines** contains the records..

but the problem is, it displays:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 

)
Array
(
    [0] =>  

)
Array
(
    [0] =>     

)
Array
(
    [0] => 

)
Array
(
    [0] => 

)
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-01-19 03:00:00
    [1] => 1.33019
    [2] => 1.33142
    [3] => 1.33019
    [4] => 1.33081
    [5] => 637

)
Array
(
    [0] => 2013-01-19 03:15:00
    [1] => 1.33083
    [2] => 1.33129
    [3] => 1.33069
    [4] => 1.33095
    [5] => 425

)

......
```

i dont know where the zeroes (empty arrays) came from.

is there something wrong with the code? 
thanks for the help..

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first `@` instead of exploding it :

```
foreach($lines as $line){
    // remove the first character
    $record = substr($line,1);
    $val = explode(',',$record);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($val);
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

Exploding on the `@` is producing an empty value in your `$data` array - [see here](http://codepad.org/L3YdeCgT)

Answer (score 0):

remove $data = explode('@', $line); if not needed or change it ur need

```
$lines[] = '2013-01-19 02:45:00,1.32927,1.33029,1.32909,1.33018,464';
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $data = explode('@', $line);
        foreach($data as $record){
            $val = explode(',',$record);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($val);
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
```